# How do I check for a mysql database change without refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to be able to have my main page (index.php) check every 10 seconds for a change in the mysql database table 'refresh'. If the 'refresh' value is 1 it needs to refresh the page in its entirety. If the value is zero it does nothing. I would use meta-refresh but I cannot have the page always refreshing as the page has a slider and it would mess up the rotation. Please let me know what you think of! Thanks in advance!

Comment: search for ajax long polling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AJAX to check if an update is required.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You should learn the [basic how to's of AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) before using something like jQuery when you don't even know what's going on.

Comment: Could you provide me some example code.